# Bootstrap carousel more slides linked to one indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using Bootstrap carousel control and I need to use **less indicators than slides**. So for example for slide 1 - 3 the first indicator will be active. When I click to another indicator, it will skip to slide 4.

I tried to solve it by having all of indicators in HTML, but hiding some of them with `display: none`. Then with JS find active slide, remove `.active` class and add it to the right indicator.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ul class="carousel-indicators">
   <!-- For these three only #a indicator should be active -->
   <li id="a" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li id="a1" class="hidden" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li id="a2" class="hidden" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

   <!-- another group -->
   <li id="b" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    if ($("#a1").hasClass("active")) {
        $("#a1").removeClass("active");
        $("#a").addClass("active");
    } else if ($("#a2").hasClass("active")) {
        $("#a2").removeClass("active");
        $("#a").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Here is an example - https://jsfiddle.net/9x5u7kjx/2/

I think this is not elegant solution at all, so is there any better way to do it?

---

**EDIT:**
I will try to explain it more clearly.

There are for example 12 slides, which slide automatically one by one. They can be controlled by arrows (left and right). **But there are only 4 indicators** (those circles below carousel). And for slide 1 - 3 the first indicator should be active, for 4 - 6 the second one and so on.

So I can slide one by one item using arrows, but when I click second indicator the carousel will skip to slide 4.

Have a look at the example, it works as it should, but I think this could be solved better.

Comment: Consider editing your question, its unclear what you are asking

Comment: are you saying that on clicking the next indicator, your slide should move to 2nd slide rather than to 4th slide ?

Comment: I am sorry, is it more understandable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Carousel with 4 indicators instead of 12

### 1. Standard indicators. CSS trick

Bootstrap's indicators are transparent except the active one. So I put them on top of each other and received two stacks of three indicators each.

The second and third indicators lie below the first indicator. Therefore, just the first indicator reacts on the click.

```
.carousel-indicators > li:nth-of-type(3n+2),
.carousel-indicators > li:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Bootstrap's active indicator is wider by 2 pixels than inactive one. It needs to move 1 pixel more than the others.

```
.carousel-indicators > li.active:nth-of-type(3n+2),
.carousel-indicators > li.active:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

Check the result:

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/346n1cwo/

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-indicators > li:nth-of-type(3n+2),
.carousel-indicators > li:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.carousel-indicators > li.active:nth-of-type(3n+2),
.carousel-indicators > li.active:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="5"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="7"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="8"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="9"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="10"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="11"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=0" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=5" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=6" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=7" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=8" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=9" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=10" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=11" alt=""></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="alert text-center">
  Bootstrap carousel with 4 standard indicators instead of 12 by CSS trick
</div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### 2. Custom indicators. jQuery

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/0L97fuzw/

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var CLASS_CAROUSEL    = '#carousel-example-generic';
  var CLASS_INDICATORS  = '#carousel-indicators';
  var CLASS_ACTIVE      = CLASS_INDICATORS + '>li.active';
  var selectCarousel    = $(CLASS_CAROUSEL); 

  selectCarousel.on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var indexTarget = $(e.relatedTarget).index();
    indexTarget = indexTarget - indexTarget % 3;
    
    var selectTarget = $(CLASS_INDICATORS + '>li[data-slide-to="' + indexTarget + '"]');
    if ( !selectTarget.hasClass('active') ) {
      $(CLASS_ACTIVE).removeClass('active');
      selectTarget.addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  width: 100%;
}

/* design */
.carousel-indicators > li,
.carousel-indicators > li.active{
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 28px; /* = height - 2 * border-width */
  margin: 0 1px; 
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 70px;
}
.carousel-indicators > li {
  border-color: #666;
  color: #666;
}
.carousel-indicators > li:hover {
  background-color: #fee;
}
.carousel-indicators > li.active {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

/* location */
.carousel-indicators {
  margin: 6px 0;
  position: static;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=0" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=5" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=6" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=7" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=8" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/9c6/fff/?text=9" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/c69/fff/?text=10" alt=""></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="img-responsive" src="//placehold.it/1200x300/69c/fff/?text=11" alt=""></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next"> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<!-- Indicators -->
<ol id="carousel-indicators" class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">0 - 2</li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">3 - 5</li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="6">6 - 8</li>
  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="9">9 - 11</li>
</ol>

<div class="alert text-center">
  Bootsrap carousel with 4 custom indicators instead of 12 by jQuery
</div>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, smart solution! But if I had custom indicators with text in it and they would overlay each other, the text is a bit bolder and borders as well. See here - https://jsfiddle.net/wwjhfv4c/. Is there a way to fix it with some absolute positioning?

Comment: @jstorm31 I've solves the task by jQuery. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @jstorm31 That's the link to [The HTML+CSS solution for custom indicators](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/hukzorzm/). I afraid that it is too difficult to use.

Comment: One more question, I applied the jQuery solution, but the `.active` class changes **after** the code is executed even though the bootstrap.js file is before my custom.js file. How is this possible? Could it be something with my environment?

Comment: @jstorm31 Bootstrap's carousel class exposes [two events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events) . `slide.bs.carousel`  fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked. `slid.bs.carousel` is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition. So check the letter `e` in your script.

Comment: I know, the carousel has two events. But `slid.bs.carousel` event is not suitable for this. What exactly should I check about `e`? Please, have a look - https://jsfiddle.net/2a92b07y/. Exactly the same jQuery code as you posted. I have some custom classes for design, because I have more carousels on a page, but it shouldn`t affect it, should it? What am I missing?

Comment: @jstorm31 I've noticed 3 problems in your jsfiddle. 1) Add `});` at the end of javascript. 2) Move indicators out of carousel. Otherwise, the carousel will switch indicators at each change of slide. 3) Shift slide numbers by one. Carousel uses  numbers, starting from zero. 12 slides get numbers from 0 to 11. Indicators use numbers from 0 to 11 too. But slides show images with numbers from 1 to 12. https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/76kczyan/

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't notice the indicators are out of the carousel. Now everything is clear. Those `});` missing were just copy & paste mistake.